# Need to fetch date, and get for how many hours date is booked from mysql

Tags: mysql

I am working on hotel booking, In which i am storing `pickup_date` and `return_date` data, table name is `booked`, I need to get date from booked table and need to check for how many hours that date is booked, can anyone please help me for this query, i don't have idea how to get that, Here i have added my table data, and also added my required output

`Booked table`

[image]

I need its output as below :

```
|----Date---|---Duration---|
|2019-06-06 |    18.15     | 
|2019-06-07 |    19.45     | 
|2019-06-08 |    21.15     | 
|2019-06-09 |    24.00     | 
|2019-06-10 |    24.00     | 
|2019-06-11 |    24.00     | 
|2019-06-12 |    09.00     |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function TIMEDIFF()

```
SELECT pickup_date, TIMEDIFF(return_date, pickup_date) duration FROM booked
```

Duration will be returned in format HH:MM:SS. Not exactly what you want but you can play with that result

Comment: but then for 2019-06-08, it will give me 90 hours which is wrong, i need 24 hours duration per date